# Wordpress: Scripts are not working properly

Tags: jquery, wordpress, function, include, anonymous

I am trying to make this work for quite a long time and I am still getting errors.

I am developing a new Wordpress page, version 4.0, on localhost. I am not able to get jQuery and other scripts to work.

I learned, I have to include scripts and styles in functions.php. Jquery is already registered, so I should only enqueue it. I also want one extra script.js file for other scripts. 
Here's my code

```
function my_scripts_styles()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

     /*   REGISTER ALL JS FOR SITE */
    wp_register_script('my_scripts', get_template_directory_uri() .  '/js/scripts.js');

    /*   REGISTER ALL CSS FOR SITE */
    wp_register_style('default',get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css');


/*   CALL ALL CSS AND SCRIPTS FOR SITE */
    wp_enqueue_script('my_scripts');
    wp_enqueue_style('default');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_styles' );
```

The CSS is working, but I the file scripts is not loaded properly or something is wrong with the code.  It contains following testing code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('div').hide();
    console.log("FFFF");
});
```

but I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (Anonymous function)

I guess it's due to the compatibility mode, but I haven't found so far what I am doing wrong.

Comment: its $('div').hide();

Comment: Typo, corrected, but the same result.

Comment: or sometimes the $ in the function( $ ). check for the line number in your browser console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't believe that.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('div').hide();
    console.log("FFFF");
});
```

IS A RIGHT ANSWER, only you have to have this script in a correct file!!!! Sorry, guys, I have copied the files from another project and I was changing a wrong file. This is very stupid, but finally it's working!

Answer (score 0):

You could write

```
$(function() {
   $('div').hide();
   console.log("FFFF");
});
```